# Calling Sharepoint with parameters

Tags: 2013, parameter

I have the following challenge ahead and have no Idea where to start with regards to the SharePoint part.

- SharePoint document library with meta data, Country, state and suburb for each document
- Stand alone C# .net application - customer data, a customer will have the following values Country, state and suburb.
- in Application-A I want to add a push button - 'Relevant Documentation', when the user clicks on the push button we can retrieve the country, state and suburb from Application-A database (don't need help with this).

*This is where I need some detailed guidance.*

- Now we need to send the parameters to SharePoint and display only the documents where the metadata corresponds to the input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# CSOM in order to retrieve the items in the list. And using a CAML query to only get the data you need.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepointurl");
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listname");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = String.Format("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Country'/><Value type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query>", lookupCountry);

var items = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```